# Why "int i = (byte) + (char) - (int) + (long) - 1" is 1?

Tags: java

I stumbled upon this code on internet

```
public class Test {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = (byte) + (char) - (int) + (long) - 1;
        System.out.println(i);

    }

}
```

It prints `1`.

Can i know why ?

Here is the source --> http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/10/weird-funny-java.html

Comment: Can i know why the downvote ?

Comment: Break the line yup and look at the values

Comment: These are all unary operators and casts.

Comment: -1 Because it is copy question; link shows it isn't... so [LMGTFY](http://goo.gl/kyktF2)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```java
int i = (byte) + (char) - (int) + (long) - 1;
            ^-------^--------^-------^ Type casting
```

`+ - + -` are assigning the sign *([Unary Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html))* to the number, so `-` then `+` then `-` and finally `+` gives you `1`.

If we just *ignore* the type casts we have `(+(-(+(-(1)))))=1`

Equivalent code:

```java
long a = (long) - 1;
int b = (int) + a;
char c = (char) - b;
int finalAns = (byte) + c;
System.out.println(finalAns); // gives 1
```

Answer (score 15):

Because after operator precedence rules are applied it becomes equivalent to:

```
int i = (byte) ((char) -((int) ((long) -1)));
```

which evaluates to `-(-1)` which is `1`.

Answer (score 8):

Due to type casting it's equivalent to

```
public class Test {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long a1 = -1;
    int a2 = a1; //still -1
    char a3 = -a2; // 1
    byte a4 = a3; // 1
    int i = a4; // 1
    System.out.println(i);

}

}
```